# Coordinate Projection Packages for PHP

Tags: php, coordinates, gis, geospatial, proj

I have coordinates in an obscure Coordinate Reference System (CRS) which I would like to project to the well-known CRS of WGS84. I want to be able to do this server-side in PHP, instead of using the JavaScript packages I have used so far. Are there any PHP packages out there which allows for coordinate projection with either a lot of Coordinate Systems or with an easy way to add a new CRS to project from? Preferably with a free-to-use commercial license such as MIT/BSD-2.

I have tried JavaScript packages so far which work fine but result in slow processing time on the front-end. I would like to find a package to use server-side in PHP.

Comment: I've never used it but there's this https://github.com/dvdoug/PHPCoord